# Apache Tomcat - PS Old Gen Filling Analysis

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, jvm, ram

I have a webserver with some applications on Tomcat, with 4GB of RAM as the maximum consumption adjusted for the JVM and the truth is that the performance is very good.
But I see that as time passes, little by little the PS Old Gen sector is filling up. The increase is 1% approx per day -->

23/01 :

[23/01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9320S.png)

24/01 :

[24/01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjxu1.png)

Is this alarming?
I've been following up for 15 days and that's how it progresses.
At the system events level there are no alerts or errors from the GC, according to the provider of the implemented product, errors should not occur (since you don't see events in the OS, they don't give importance to you) but should i worry?

According to all the documentation that I read, at the moment of reaching 100% a GC will be executed on said sector and it will continue in operation, but since it hasn't happened so far, I'm interested in asking experts on the matter.

What do you think? What kind of logs should I check apart from system events and tomcat logs?

Thanks!,
Regards.

PS Old Gen Filling Analysis

Answer (score 0):

well you can try to analyze heap dump of you application to see what is stored in memory, also gc log could be useful here, in general full gc can free your old gen memory

Comment: OK, i will investigate how to check that info (head dump and gc log). Thanks!